# How to open file:///sharedDrive url in same window in browser using java

Tags: java, javascript, url, httpresponse

I tried to open file:///sharedDrive url in new window of broswer using

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Folder</button>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
window.open("file://///sharedDrive/folder/");
}
</script>
```

Its opening url in IE, but not in Firefox/Chrome.

Even i tried to open this url using

```
reponse.sendRedirect("file://///sharedDrive/folder/");
```

But its appending localhost:port\ before opening this url.

Comment: Using Java? Or JavaScript? What are you trying to do?

Comment: i tried both, but not getting desired result.

Comment: I thought this was a feature specific to IE, as it is more tightly integrated into the Windows filesystem.

Comment: You tried both what? You didn't try Java if you're on the client side. What are you trying to achieve? Trying to open a folder? For what purpose?

Comment: Yeah, i am trying to open folder in browser using javascript, coz of one requirement i got. Its allowing me in IE, but not in Firefox/Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

imho there is no way to open a file in chrome anyways, but it will be downloaded. Even if you type the file:// url directly in the address bar, the same happens, regardless of shared or local file. The only exceptions are pdfs and images.